# How to handle divide-by-zero error when hashing values in two sequences

Tags: python, mapping, list-comprehension

I have two lists of fixed-length tuples. This function calculates a fraction (ratio) for respective elements (note, `fX()` does not use comprehension for readability here).

```
>>> def fX(a,b):  
>>>    c=[]  
>>>    for i in range(len(a)):  
>>>        c.append([a[i][x]/float(a[i][x]+b[i][x]) for x in range(len(a[i]))])
>>>    return c
```

When all values are non-zero, `fX()` works:

```
>>> a[0]=(3, 4, 17, 9.6667, 6.6583, 0.4310, 1)  
>>> b[0]=(4, 4, 12, 8.0, 3.2660, 0.0002, 1)  
>>> fX(a,b)  
>>> [[0.4286, 0.5, 0.5862, 0.5472, 0.6710, 0.9995, 0.5]]
```

However, when any pair's values sum to zeros, `fX()` fails:

```
>>> a[0]=(3, 4, 17, 9.6667, 6.6583, 0.4310, 0)  
>>> b[0]=(4, 4, 12, 8.0, 3.2660, 0.0002, 0)  
>>> fX(a,b)  
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "<pyshell#59>", line 1, in <module>  
    fX(a,b)  
  File "<pyshell#52>", line 4, in fX  
    c.append([a[i][x]/float(a[i][x]+b[i][x]) for x in range(len(a[i]))])  
ZeroDivisionError: float division
```

I'm need a function, `fY()`, that gives this desired outcome without resorting to a brute force test of each value:

```
>>> a[i]=(3, 4, 17, 9.6667, 6.6583, 0.4310, 0)  
>>> b[i]=(4, 4, 12, 8.0, 3.2660, 0.0002, 0)  
>>> fY()  
>>> [[0.4286, 0.5, 0.5862, 0.5472, 0.6710, 0.9995, 0.0]]
```

Thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with brute force?

Comment: `[x] for x in range(len(...` is a form of brain damage caused by languages like C++. If you want to do something with all of the elements of a list, do it **with the elements of the list**, not with the elements of a temporary list of indices of the same length that you create after measuring the original. Iteratively appending to an empty list is also poor style; you already know how to use a list comprehension, so apply the same technique to the outer loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `a if x else b` ternary operator (equivalent to the C/C++/Java expression `x ? a : b`) to put the conditional inside the list comprehension.  This gives an efficient, Pythonic implementation:

```
def fY(a, b):
    return [[aij/float(aij + bij) if aij+bij != 0 else 0 for aij, bij in zip(ai, bi)]
            for ai, bi in zip(a, b)]
```

Comment: This works and is about 10% faster than other alternatives. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

```
def f_cell(a, b):
    try: return a / float(a + b) # EAFP
    except: return 0.0 # Or whatever other value you want for this case.

def fY(a,b):  
    return [
        [f_cell(a_cell, b_cell) for a_cell, b_cell in zip(a_row, b_row)]
        for a_row, b_row in zip(a, b)
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to do this in python, there is no way besides doing a test of each element. Note that this does not increase your asymptotic running time at all, and is quite cheap. It is not "brute force" at all.

If you really really cared about syntax, and didn't care at all about speed, you could wrap each number in your own custom `MyNumber` class with special rules for division. This will, of course, produce absolutely terrible overhead.

You could also wrap your computation in a `try...except` that returns `float('nan')` on exception, but that is equivalent to doing "a test of each value". Even a built-in feature of the language which did this is equivalent to doing "a test of each value" (it's just doing the test behind your back).

Answer (score -1):

Well you CAN make a hash function without checking the denominator. The trick is to guarantee the denominator is never 0. You can do this by bitwise or-ing in something into the denominator, making sure at least one non sign bit is set before division is done.

Here's a sample fY:

```
def fY(a,b):  
   c=[]  
   for i in range(len(a)):  
       # Or in a bit to make sure non zero
       c.append([float(a[i][x])/(1 | int(a[i][x]+b[i][x])) for x in range(len(a[i]))])  
   return c
```

Notice the denominator has to be turned into an int. That's the technique at least, its up to you to figure out if you can use it to make a meaningful hash function for your input. The above example for the technique may or may not be any good to you (or anyone) as a hash function. Whether or not this is a technique that lends itself to creating good readable code is also another issue.

Comment: why the downvote, I only answered what they asked. I didn't say it was *good*

Comment: @ DougT. Thanks. This works and runs in the same time as the loop. However, I need the resolution if/when the denominator is floating point.

Comment: "The denominator has to be turned into an int" because bitwise-or is totally inappropriate and illogical here. I don't know who -1'd you before, but that's why I did. Try `(a[i][x] + b[i][x]) or 1.0` if you want to go this route.